# I accidentally ran `rm -rf /` what should I do

Tags: macos, rm, bsd

I accidentally ran `rm -rf /` on my macos machine, most files were protected since I was not running the command as root, but I definitely lost some files in /usr/local, are there any other files I might have lost?

Comment: Use your handy Time Machine backup to restore the system.  Ummm... you *do* have one, don't you?

Comment: idk, it's a relatively new mac, like i got it from work 10 days ago

Comment: Easy -- go back to IT at work and have them fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably lost your homedir in /Users too.  Did you reboot afterwards?  I'm guessing your desktop/files are all gone, if you can even login.  If you can login, your homedir is probably completely fresh, as if it was your first time logging in.

Comment: i think i killed the command fast enough so it didn't reach /Users/me, it got to /AAA and /BBB first 

Comment: what's weird is it got to /usr/local/* but it didn't seem to get to /Users/me dunno